# Couldn't connect to the PD Server using `127.0.0.1` in TiDB

Tags: tidb, tidb-pd

I have deployed a TiDB cluster for testing. When I was using PD Control, I found that I could only connect to the PD server using the local IP address, but couldn't connect to it using `127.0.0.1`. I'm wondering why.

Answer (score 0):

If your TiDB cluster is deployed using TiDB-Ansible, the PD external service port is not bound to `127.0.0.1`, so PD Control won’t recognize `127.0.0.1`.